# Dynamic CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Is there anyway to have a case expression that produces different results based upon a value being an integer or a character.

Tables

```
  ID        CODE
  1         ABC
  2         123
  3         YHU
  4         456
  5         ikl
```

I was looking for an expression that separated the int and char.

Result e.g.

```
  ID        CODE    Category
  1         ABC       Char
  2         123       Int
  3         YHU       Char
  4         456       Int
  5         ikl       Char
```

my general logic

```
 CASE WHEN CODE = INT THEN 'Int' Else 'Char' end as Category
```

But i didnt know if this was possible in SQL?

I am looking mainly for a way to recognise whether its int or char

UPDATE:

What is the best way to separate the numbers from char, * and - into 2 different categories using case expression

```
  ID        CODE    Category
  1          *        No_NUM
  2         123       NUM
  3         YHU       No_NUM
  4         456       NUM
  5         ikl       No_NUM
  6          -        No_NUM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL [ISNUMERIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) function.

```
SELECT ID, CODE, CASE ISNUMERIC(CODE) WHEN 1 THEN 'NUM' ELSE 'No_NUM' END AS Category FROM my_table;
```

Another Variation with REGEX

```
SELECT ID, CODE, CASE WHEN CODE LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN 'NUM' ELSE 'No_NUM' END AS Category FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TRY_CAST` (SQL Server 2012+)

```
SELECT *,
   CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(CODE AS INT) IS NOT NULL THEN 'Int' ELSE 'Char' END
FROM tab;
```

I've assumed that column is `NOT NULL`.

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/UIHHS47285)**

EDIT:

It is just text inside `CASE`:

```
SELECT *,
   CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(CODE AS INT) IS NOT NULL THEN 'NUM' ELSE 'No_NUM' END
FROM tab;
```

**[Rextester Demo 2](http://rextester.com/WNQT28092)**

Comment: could you have a look at my update

Answer (score 0):

Use PATINDEX:

```
 create table #temp ([ID] int, [CODE] nvarchar(5))

 insert into #temp values (1, '*')
 insert into #temp values (2, '123')
 insert into #temp values (3, 'YHU')
 insert into #temp values (4, '456')
 insert into #temp values (5, 'ikl')

 Select ID
    , CASE  when PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [code]) = 1 then 'num'
         -- when PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [code]) = 1 then 'no_num'
         -- when PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', [code]) = 1 then 'char' 
         -- when PATINDEX('%[^A-Z]%', [code]) = 1 then 'no_char' /*etc..*/
      ELSE 'no_num' END AS 'Category'
 from #temp
```